# When clicking a button, how do you make video and text appear?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm actually quite lost and don't know where to start. So basically what I'm trying to achieve is when the button is clicked, the text and video will reveal. Otherwise hide it when clicked away.

*picture of how I want it* 
[preview on the html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36zcI.png)

**HTML**

```
<div id="abl1"> <!-- Ability ONE VIDEO HEAL SHOT !-->
    <video preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" type="video/mp4" src="sleepdart.mp4" loop></video>
</div>

<div class="shape1"></div>
    <p class="ability1txt">Text.</p>
<div class="button.abl">
    <button id="abl1.btn" class="ability1"></button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
abl1 video{
    height: 500px;
    width: 600px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 200px;
}


.ability1txt{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 600px;
    font-size: 27px;
    z-index: 10px;
    margin-left: 55%;
    margin-top:8%;
    font-family: "BigNoodleTitling";
    color: white;  
}
```

Comment: You need to use some JavaScript. Show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by javascript as following:

```js
function ab1_Click() {
   var vid1 = document.getElementById("ab1Video");
   var t1 = document.getElementById("ab1Text");
   var v = "visible"; 
   if (vid1.style.visibility != "hidden") { v = "hidden"; }
   vid1.style.visibility =  v; 
   t1.style.visibility = v;
}
```

```html
<div id="abl1"> <!-- Ability ONE VIDEO HEAL SHOT !-->
        <video id="ab1Video" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" type="video/mp4" src="sleepdart.mp4" loop></video>
</div>

<div class="shape1"></div>
<p id="ab1Text" class="ability1txt">Text.</p>

<div class="button.abl">
    <button id="abl1.btn" class="ability1" onclick="ab1_Click()">Show/Hide</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

You could always use raw Javascript but using jQuery makes things a whole lot easier. Generally, Javascript is used for interactivity.

Your Javascript code would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.button\.abl button#abl1\.btn').click(function() {
        if ($('div#abli video').is(':visible') && $('p.ability1txt').is(':visible')) {
            $('div#abli video').hide(); // or fadeOut()
            $('p.ability1txt').hide(); // or fadeOut()
        } else {
            $('div#abli video').show(); // or fadeIn()
            $('p.ability1txt').show(); // or fadeIn()
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This will not work! visible and show are in same branch

Comment: @S.Serp Good catch! Corrected it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need JavaScript to make video and text show/hide. By using only CSS and HTML we could hide anything with a strategically placed checkbox and label. Added some JavaScript so the video pauses when it's hidden, but the show/hide feature requested doesn't need any JavaScript.

**Details commented in Demo**

### Demo

```js
// Reference the <video> and <input type='checkbox'>
var v = document.getElementById('vid0');
var c = document.getElementById('chx0');

/* Whenever label.btn is clicked, the checkbox triggers
|| the change event. When a change happens, the <video>
|| will play if the checkbox is checked and pause if 
|| it isn't
*/
c.onchange = function(e) {
  if (this.checked) {
    v.play();
  } else {
    v.pause();
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Although .chx is "gone", it is still able to 
|| influence and be influenced by other elements
*/

.chx {
  display: none
}

.case {
  display: none;
  height: 270px;
  width: 480px;
}


/* When checkbox is checked the figure.case
|| that follows the label.btn which in turn 
|| follows the checkbox is revealed
*/

.chx:checked+.btn+.case {
  display: block;
}

#vid0 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.cap {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: white;
  display: table;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.btn {
  font-size: 48px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8ch;
  height: 2ex;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #00f;
  text-shadow: 3px 1px 2px #555;
}

.btn::before {
  content: '▶'
}


/* When the checkbox is checked, the pseudo-element
|| of label.btn that follows the checkbox changes its
|| icon to pause.
*/

.chx:checked+.btn::before {
  content: '⏸';
  font-size: 54px;
}
```

```html
<input id='chx0' class='chx' type='checkbox'>
<!-- 
[for] attribute value is the #id of the form-control it is accosiated with. This association allows the <label> to act as the form-control's proxy. Simply put, if label#btn0 is clicked, then input#chx0 is checked or unchecked.
-->
<label id="btn0" class='btn' for='chx0'></label>


<figure class="case">
  <video id='vid0' preload="auto" autoplay loop src="https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005611.mp4" width='480' height='270'></video>
  <figcaption class='cap'>1 min/11 sec Leader</figcaption>
</figure>
```